# compareTo method explain 1, -1, 0

Tags: java

Can anyone explain how the 1, -1, and 0 are used in compareTo and other methods in java? I know how the methods work to a degree, but the three numbers confuse me.

Comment: What you don't understand is unclear. Can you be more specific ? Note that the [Comparable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) doesn't specify the 1 and -1 values.

Comment: It's the `Comparable` contract; all that matters is that the result is negative, 0 or positive if the value compared to is considered less than, equal to or greater than the value you compare against.

Comment: I mean how hen you compare two things it returns 1 or -1 or 0. I don't know why it returns each.

Comment: What you seem to be confused with is that the `Comparable` interface _will not_ return a meaningful value _quantifying_ the difference between two instances; this is not what `Comparable` is for. A quantifiable difference is _yours_ to compute, but `Comparable` won't do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) return from the method `compareTo(obj)` is:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

This mean that if you invoke method on current object `this.compareTo(obj)` and **by your own logic** in method `compareTo` `this` object grater than `obj` that you passed to method, return would be a positive integer.

Your own logic mean that, for example in object that you compare to other, exist some integer field and if this field greater than other field in other object, **by your logic**, you consider that this object greater than other.