# Possible values of Integer.compare

Tags: java, integer, compare

In the documentation for Integer.compare(a,b) it says, that it will return a value below 0, if a is smaller than b, and a value above 0 if a is bigger than b.

After I have implemented the method in my code, I have only ever seen it return -1, 0 or 1. My question now is, can it return other values as well, for example -5?

I have to write code where I override the compareTo method, and it has to only return -1, 0, or 1, no other values. In my compareTo I use Integer.compare, so I am wondering if there will be any cases where it will return values outside of -1, 0, 1.

Comment: This is related to the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541075/compareto-method-explain-1-1-0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After I have implemented the method in my code, I have only ever seen it return -1, 0 or 1. My question now is, can it return other values as well, for example -5?

Yes, it can. The current implementation may only return the values you observed, but there is nothing to stop the implementation changing in the future.

> I have to write code where I override the compareTo method, and it has to only return -1, 0, or 1, no other values. In my compareTo I use Integer.compare, so I am wondering if there will be any cases where it will return values outside of -1, 0, 1.

With the result of `Comparable.compareTo` (or `Comparator.compare`, or similar method), you should only ever check the result in relation to zero, that is: `== 0`, `< 0` or `> 0` (or `!=`, `<=` or `>=`).

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe they will change the implementation, but it is very easy to modify these return values to [-1,0,1].

Here is the code:

```java
int modifiedCompareTo(Integer a, Integer b) {
    int res = a.compareTo(b);
    return res == 0 ? 0 : res/Math.abs(res);
}
```

Comment: This isn't actually correct: if `a.compareTo(b)` returned `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, this method would return 1 (demo: https://ideone.com/S5lFKw). But aside from that, don't do this: firstly, because it requires you to remember to call this method instead of the entirely standard `Integer.compare` method; secondly, because you should simply code against the documented behaviour: less than zero, zero, or zero is returned: making it return -1, 0, 1 is essentially unnecessary.